# Flag edits which introduce errors?

Tags: discussion, edits

I recently came across a post which had been edited, but during the edit, a clear error has been introduced in the code originally posted by the OP

see here
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24526457/revisions
revision 2

The edit changed

```
int nickels = 0;
```

into

```
int double nickels = 0;
```

which is obviously wrong. I suggested (and got approved) an edit to revert this change.

My question is: is there any way to deal with this kind of edits other than reverting them?

Here the problem I see is that not only did the edit introduce illegal code but it could have potentially even changed the code originally posted in a way that would have obfuscated the problem posted originally by the OP, e.g. by changing `int nickels` to `double nickels` which is very close to what the edit resulted in.

Comment: The **problem** here, as this always boils down to, is that the robo-reviwers who saw this edit [***blindly*** accepted it](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5199468). The recourse here is to ban them from reviewing.

Comment: @Matt so my question could be amended to say: is there a way to flag reviewers that don't check carefully before approving? Obviously something like this can happen, but if, as you say, people just blindly approve everything, then eventually blocking them is the right course of action.

Comment: @Erik flag the post with a link to the suggested edit, in this case http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5199468.  The mod that responds to your flag will deal with the reviewers if it is deemed necessary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First and foremost, fix the edit. You did that. Good!

Then leave a comment for the editor - yes, you can address any editor on a post via a comment, by mentioning their name prefixed with an @-symbol:

> @Erik, please be more careful with your edits.

Etc.

Finally, click through to the [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5199468) edit and check the reviewer stats. If it appears they make a habit of approving this sort of thing, you might wish to flag the post for moderator attention. If it appears to be a simple mistake, don't bother. (I've given the approvers in this instance a little heads-up already, so don't bother flagging it)

Comment: Ahah, I never new editors were reachable that way! Would’ve saved me some trouble had I known. Thanks for revealing the Secrets of the Ancients.