# How to flag an edit?

Tags: discussion, flags, revision-history, rollback-wars

There does not seem to be any obvious way how to flag an edit. In [this revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26809266/revisions) there have been several incidents:

I retagged at #2, user undid this at #3, I rolled back with [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26809266/bertrand-russell-puzzle#comment42191591_26809266) to user at #4, user removed again at #6. So I gave up and flagged the question. Now about 10 days later, my flagging was deemed useful, but nothing else happened.

The next incident is at #8, where someone entirely defaced the program. I rolled back, but there does not seem to be a way to justify this.

What should I have done instead?

Comment: Why don't you just rollback and leave an appropriate comment?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: #8 was an anonymous reviewed edit (with some but not enough reviewers rejecting the edit)

Comment: Related: [Flag edits which introduce errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262244/603977)

Comment: I simply flag posts affected by troublesome edits (I vaguely recall it didn't feel obvious to me 2 or 3 years ago)

Comment: Yesterday, I flagged a user for his/her incorrect edits. My flag deemed helpful, I thought he/she would lose rep gained from such edits but nothing happend. I don't know if such users get notified for such behaviour.

Comment: @Omar: I again got helpful flags, but the issue is not fixed. I do not care about rep, but it seems the flagging has no other effect than increasing the helpful count to get the [deputy badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1002/deputy)

Comment: I guess they get banned from suggesting edits. I have checked both users profiles (your case and mine) there is no new activity in "revisions" tab.

Comment: @Omar: hm, but then I should redo the edit, should I not?

Comment: If it's incorrect, fix it without hesitation.

Comment: @Omar: This would be the 3rd time I fix it...

Comment: Doesn't matter, if it needs to be fixed, then it should be fixed.

Comment: @Omar personally I disagree.  If you get into an edit war then nothing constructive will actually be done.  While I don't know off the top of my head where the meta post about that is, I'm pretty sure it exists and essentially states "If you get into an edit war stop and either flag for a moderator or bring it up on meta".  There are better ways for us to spend our time than going back and forth in an edit war

Comment: @Dannnno makes sense. A moderator should interfere, at least _lock_ the post to prevent/avoid edit war.

Comment: Flagging the post was correct, there's no need to flag individual edits. What text did you put in for the reason of your flag?

Comment: Why tag this question with `[clpb]` in Revision 7? A commonality between the answers does not imply a restriction on the question.

Comment: @AirThomas: Because this is a question that has an answer using [clpb].

Comment: @False Just because an answer is given in a language doesn't mean the question should be tagged that way. One could easily answer a JavaScript question with jQuery (as is the old SO meme), but that doesn't mean the question should then be tagged as jQuery.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: This is entirely OT to this question. If you believe this, then please make a new question.

Comment: You are asking about proper editing practices, and accusing another user of not following them, so it's not *entirely* off topic to at least do a sanity check to make sure *you* are following proper editing practices.

Comment: @Bergi: essentially what happened to that point.